# Excel VBA: Copy from data to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I risk loosing reputation with this question, but I need a programmer not a power user. I'm able to write in PHP, but Excel VBA is out of my league and I need quick solution.

I got an Excel file with 2 sheets, "Form" and "Data". In fist sheet is a button "Save". When a user clicks this button I need these things to happen:

- Copy the data from different columns in sheet "Form" (in this example C2 and C4)
- Paste data to a new row into sheet "Data" on a new row, both columns horizontally
- Clear columns in sheet "Form"

The code is:

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Sheets("Form").Range("C2,C4")
    For Each cell In r
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            MsgBox ("Error - all boxes must be filled in!")
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Dim NextRow As Range
    Set NextRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:L2").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Set NextRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
    Sheets("Form").Range("C2,C4").Copy
    NextRow.PasteSpecial (xlValues)

    MsgBox ("Data added successfully!")

    Sheets("Form").Range("C2,C4").ClearContents

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
end sub
```

I already wrote a script, but the columns copy under each other vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Comment: Can you please post your VB? It's bad form asking people to download and open a file, especially one that could potentially be malicious via macro.

Comment: Thanks B80Buckeye, I added the code.

Comment: Given your recent comment to the answer below, what are the cells you want to copy and where do you want to put them. My crystal ball crashed this morning due to updates and I'm having a hard time getting it booted up properly.

Comment: I didn't wanted to bother with all the details. I need more cells. In my real scenario the range is exactly B3;E3;E10:E11;G10:G11;I10:I11;K10:K11;M10:M11;E24:E40;G24:G40;I24:I40;K24:K40;M24:M40;E43:G45

And I want all these cells from sheet "Form" to be copied to sheet "Data" as a single row like A1,B1,C1,D1 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After browsing Stackoverflow for another 3 hours, I finally get all I needed. I hope this will help others.

Whole point was in "Transpose:=True".

```
Dim NextRow As Range
'find next clear row, set it as target'
Set NextRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

'copy the cell values from range'
Sheets("Form").Range("C2,C4").Copy

'paste values as horizontal line into target'
NextRow.PasteSpecial (xlValues), Transpose:=True
```

Answer (score 2):

You want Form cells C2 & C4 to end up in the 1 empty row in Data sheet

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click()
    Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Worksheets("Form").Range("C2")
    Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Worksheets("Form").Range("C4")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This would do the trick, but I wanted to work with range as array of multiple columns. In my real case I will be working with 99 columns. The code would be a mess.